# NSToolbarItem is always nil in cocoa touch (os x) Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa-touch, iboutlet, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I have set IBOutlet for NSSearchField but it's always find nil in .m file. Why???

If have any idea then please give answer related to my issues.[image]

Comment: Do the other outlets connected to toolbar item controls work?

Comment: Not work All toolbar item controls. Please help.

Comment: The app delegate in the Application Scene is a place holder. Did you add another app delegate to the Window Controller Scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your storyboard, you created `NSObject` of `Appdelegate` and through that object you create outlet, that's why its not accessible.

So, you have to create `NSWindowController` class and assign this class to `WindowController` in storyboard. Then declare outlet in that class.

Now it is accessible and work as you want.

Comment: Thanks @Jitendra Modi